# After inherit the class from "Access" class getting an error while using "protected" keyword

Tags: c#, inheritance

I'm new in csharp and i found that if i do using `protected` keyword in child class then it can only be accessed inside child not in parent class. and also This type of variable or function can only be accessed in child class.
I was reading tutorial from [this](http://www.completecsharptutorial.com/basic/protected.php).

But if i do `inherit` from Access class that must suppose to be not given any kind of error but i get it. Can you tell me what's wrong here?

here is my code:

```
using System;

class Access
{

    //here string is declared as protected ..
    protected string name;

    public void print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MY name is: {0}", name);
    }
}

class MyProgram: Access
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Access ac1=new Access();

        Console.WriteLine("Enter your name: ");

        ac1.name = Console.ReadLine();
        ac1.print();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This type of variable or function (protected) can only be accessed in
>   child class

```
Access ac1=new Access();
... 
ac1.name = Console.ReadLine(); //You would be getting error here.
```

This is quite obvious as you are not accessing the `protected` member of base class through the instance of derived class but you are creating object of base class i.e. Access and trying to access its `protected` member which results in error.

If you create object of derived class i.e. MyProgram then you will be able to access the `protected` member.

```
MyProgram p=new MyProgram();
p.name = Console.ReadLine(); // No Error!!
```

Answer (score 0):

**The protected member can only be accessed by code in the same class or struct, or in a derived class.**

```
ac1.name = Console.ReadLine();
```

You are trying to access name through object of `Access`(Base class) which is not allowed for protected members. If you want to access it either change it public or access through object of `MyProgram` (Derived class).

```
MyProgram p=new MyProgram();
p.name = Console.ReadLine(); // allowed as MyProgram is derived class from Access class
```

Answer (score 0):

yoou are not using inheritance here

```
Access ac1=new Access();
```

you are making object here and calling the protected member that is not available for use.

If you want to use inheritance then do it like

```
class MyProgram: Access
{
    //Make a non-static method and this field would be available
    public void ma()
    {
        //you will find the field here
        this.name ="some name"
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      //Error here
      Access ac1=new Access();

      Console.WriteLine("Enter your name: ");

      //field would not be available here because you are making object
      ac1.name = Console.ReadLine();
      ac1.print();

     //Do it like

     //it would work because of inheritance
     var localObject = new MyProgram()
     localObject.name = Console.ReadLine();
     localObject.print();
    }
}
```